# default consumer URL for spring boot saml dsl

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, saml, dsl, spring-saml

What is the default Consumer URL for Spring boot saml dsl? Wanted to confirm if this is `/saml/SSOHoK`
I am trying to implement a simple spring boot webapp, and trying to override the default consumer URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default URI would be

```
/saml/SSO
```